# Mongodb driver installed but not showing up in php modules.

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, php-mongodb

PHP was giving me the following error:

```
Type: Error
Message: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
File: $/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php
Line: 87
```

So I installed the mongodb driver on MacOSX High Sierra version 10.13.5 with the following command after disabling the csrutil:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Then I added `extension=mongodb.so` to the php.ini file.

Now when I use the command:

```
php -m
```

to list the php module, mongodb is not showing up in the list.

PHP Version : PHP 7.1.16

pecl/mongodb version : 1.5.2

What can be the possible reason for this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you restarted your server ? if not do it.

If this won't help check if you edited right php.ini

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: Yep. Had to restart the server.